# Vim Register Use in Ex Mode

Tags: vim, scripting, vim-registers

Potentially 2 questions in one.  I would like to know how to reference a register in Ex mode.

For instance, I'm editing a file and I want to save the file with a timestamp (or just datestamp really) appended to it.

I know I can set register to the value of a shell commands output using:

```
:let @a = system("date +\"%Y-%m-%d\"")
```

Is there any to dereference this register and insert its value into an Ex command? Something like:

```
:w testfile.<value of "a register>
```

Copying to the system clipboard and pasting would be nice, but doing it in a more generic/programitic way for building on other commands in the future would be nice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two approaches to doing this, but probably neither are exactly what you want.

1. Use `<CTRL-R>a` to insert the contents in the current command line.  See `:help c_CTRL-R` for more info.
2. Use `exe` to allow insertion of variables into the expression.  See `:help :exe` and `:help 41.3`.

   ```
   :exe 'w testfile.' . @a
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming register "a", you can type:

`<CTRL-R>a` which will input the value of register a inline at that point. This can be used in insert mode as well.

Comment: Yeah, knew about that, looking for a way to do it without having to paste it in.  No particular reason, but would be nice to have something that would automatically dereferences the variable